# this.getView() is not working - SAPUI5

Tags: controller, this, sapui5

I've been trying to use `this.getView()` on my controllers a couple of times but I'm always getting getView is not a function error on my console.

Is there any "trick" or something that I can do to make this work?

Heres's an example of how I'm using it (this is a function I've created in my controller):

```
formatIconStatus: function(status){
         var view = this.getView();
         if (status != null){
             if (status == "YES"){
                 status = "sap-icon://accept";
             }else{
                 status = "sap-icon://error";
             }
             return status;
         }
     },
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try a `console.log("this", this);` as first command in the function to check what `this` actually is.

Comment: this M.c…s.f {bAllowTextSelection: true, mEventRegistry: Object, sId: "__status14-__table0-0", mProperties: F, mAggregations: Object…} - This function is being called in a table formatter for a status formatter. So, the "this" is point to that cell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there is. If you are using a JSView `this` in formatter functions and event listeners points to the Control it belongs to. For **formatter functions** you can change this by assigning the function like in this example:

```
new sap.m.Button({
    text : {
        path : "/buttonText",
        formatter : $.proxy(oController.myTextFormatter, oController);
    }
});
```

With the help of [jQuery.proxy](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) you can set `this` within `myTextFormatter` to `oController`. This allows you to call `this.getView()` within your formatter since `this` will now point to the controller.

In order to set the scope for **event listeners** you can either assign the function the same way as shown above or you can use a different approach offered by the framework like in the following example:

```
new sap.m.Button({
    press : [oController.myPressHandler, oController]
});
```

Using this notation, the framework will call the event listener (myPressHandler) with the *second entry* of the array as scope.

This pattern is valid for most event listeners across the UI5 framework. Basically, you have three options when assigning event listeners:

- fnListenerFunction
- [fnListenerFunction, oListenerScope]
- [oData, fnListenerFunction, oListenerScope]

Using XMLViews you don´t have to set the scope manually as it´s set to the associated controller by default.

Comment: Why it returned `oController is not defined` ?

Comment: I solved my event listeners' problem by using `button.attachPress(this.onAddStop.bind(this))`